# WebRTC facingMode environment not working in Android Chrome

Tags: webrtc, webrtc-android, android-chrome

I am using WebRTC for video and audio and I want to support flipping the camera in a mobile device from front to back and vice versa.

Using the below code Safari iOS works great, but Android Chrome will throw the exception `NotReadableError: Could not start video source`.
I am also closing any previous track.

```
var constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
        "width": {
            "ideal": 1280
        },
        "height": {
            "ideal": 720
        },
        "facingMode": {
            "exact": "environment"
        },
    },
}

const userMedia = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints) // Will throw - NotReadableError: Could not start video source
```

I also tried the constraints without width and height.

```
{
  "audio": false,
  "video": {
    "facingMode": {
      "exact": "environment"
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to debug further or try things out will be appreciated.

[Update]
Testing with Android Firefox browser works as expected!

Comment: FYI, on my end, using `facingMode: 'environment'` works just fine. Maybe try removing the "exact" requirement to see if it goes through, this might lead you to the solution?

Comment: Will try it out thanks!

Comment: facingMode: 'environment' not work